# Trying to use 'import' and 'export' es6 using sprockets-es6 in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, babeljs, systemjs

I'm trying to use 'import' and 'export' keywords of es6 as explained on babeljs getting started using the [sprockets-es6](https://github.com/TannerRogalsky/sprockets-es6) gem in Rails 4.

Can someone give an example of how to use it ? I'm getting error saying 'import' should be present on top.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to help if you could provide your code snippet and the stack trace of the error you are getting.

However based on the information you have provided, I am guessing you are not using import statement at top level, which the [ES2015 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports) mandates.

The [chapter](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) on ES6 modules from the book [exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com) is the best resource I can recommend you at this point.